# How to incorporate Jquery UI sortable code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to incorporate Jquery UI sortable into the the unordered list I have below.  When I click on the button in the form below, it insets the text into #companyassessment_set1 and then submits the form.

When I try to include the javascript for the sortable part, nothing works (existing jquery code + sortable functionality).  The code is here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#menu-pages').sortable();
});
```

rest of code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

   <script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery(function () {
    $('#test').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('test');
        data = 'Benefits,Predictable hours,Up or out,Job for life,Great corporate strategic vision,Strong profitability,Performance-based,Strong alumni network,Effective managers,Fast growth,Salary and bonus,Little ranking between employees,No working on the weekends,Competitive environment,Great brand for the resume,International opportunities,Brand recognition,Smart people,Stock growth,Perks,No layoffs,Type-A employees,Fast advancement,Reasonable hours'
        $("#companyassessment_set1").val(data);
        $("form#new_companyassessment").submit();

    });
}); 
</script>
```

```
    <p>
        <label for="companyassessment_Company Name">Company name</label><br />
        <div class="field_with_errors"><input id="companyassessment_name" name="companyassessment[name]" size="30" type="text" value="" /></div>
    </p>

    <ul class="menu" id="menu-pages">
        <li id="page_1">Home</li>
        <li id="page_2">Blog</li>
        <li id="page_3">About</li>

    </ul>


        <input id="companyassessment_set1" name="companyassessment[set1]" type="hidden" />



<input id="test" type="button" value="Set Value" />
```

Any advice on how to incorporate the Jquery UI code?

Comment: what you are sorting here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second jquery reference is overwriting the jqueryui reference and so your sortable method isn't recognized. Remove this and you should be okay:

```
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Also the line where you define the 'data' variable needs a semi-colon at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#menu-pages" ).sortable();
$( "#menu-pages" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>
```

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

d di you look int o this view source

Comment: When I do this, I'm still not able to select the elements in the unordered list.